# SQL STDEVP as analytical function (calculate standard deviation per account)

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

T is is table with transactions.
For a specific period I am taking all accounts and sum the amount of transactions each account had per day.
I then want to calculate the standard deviation per day.
I am using the below query, but instead of giving me 1 row for each account, for each account I get the number of rows equal to the number of days the account has data.
I am expecting the patriation to work like group by..
I can use distinct, but I would like to understand why does it behave this way and if indeed distinct is the right solution.

```
with prevActivity AS
(
    SELECT AccountID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T.TransactionDate, 101) AS TrxDate, SUM(T.amount) AS amountPerday 
    FROM T -- table with transactions
    WHERE T.TransactionDate BETWEEN  DATEADD(DAY,-100,GETDATE() - 1) AND GETDATE() - 1
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.TransactionDate, 101),
             last24Summary.AccountID
), variance AS
(
    SELECT prevActivity.AccountID, STDEVP(prevActivity.amountPerday) OVER (PARTITION BY prevActivity.AccountID) AS AmountSTDDev
    FROM prevActivity
)
SELECT *
FROM variance
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Lots of product specific functions used.)

Comment: @jarlh sorry, didn't understand the question. What's dbms?

Comment: dbms = database management system, i.e. "the sql database". For example MS SQL Server, Postgresql, DB2 etc.

Comment: sorry, Microsoft SQL

Comment: No problem. With the <sql server> tag, the question will get better, and more accurate attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation, not window functions:

```
SELECT pa.AccountID, STDEVP(pa.amountPerday) AS AmountSTDDev,
       AVG(pa.amountPerday) as AmountAvg
FROM prevActivity pa
GROUP BY pa.AccountID;
```

I threw in the average as well, because the two often go together.

Also note that you are using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.TransactionDate, 101)` to extract the date.  The logic `CONVERT(DATE, T.TransactionDate)` is not only simpler, but the intent is also much clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much. Aggregation was the first thing I tried. I probably had some unrelated error and decided it cannot be used as aggregation function. And thanks for the convert tip!